# Wordpress frontpage still redirects to old url after migration

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

So I moved my site from https://kogutorium.org/wordpress to https://kogutorium.org/ (there was another site earlier but i deleted all old files with old .htaccess file)

I updated settings "home url" and "site url". Everything works fine but... Frontpage (and **ONLY FRONTPAGE**) still redirects to the https://kogutorium.org/wordpress. Other pages works well.

This is what i get when i check redirects path:

[image]

Any ideas what should i check?

I'm using also Yoast SEO (without premium)

Answer (score 0):

Kindly, Verify These points:

1. Your Site URL From wp dashbard  from Settings < General..
2. Enter the phpmyadmin and check the site url and home url from wp-options table.